# Isn't the word "uninstall" wrong?

Tags: meaning, verbs, negation, prefixes, morphology

I've never understood this. Why is the proper usage "uninstall"? You can't actually "unin" something at all and this isn't that case with most (all?) other use cases. Examples:

- You make someone sane, but you don't uninsane them.
- You make something accessible but never uninaccessible something.
- You can make something adequate but never uninadequate something.

Comment: "Install" is a verb -- all of your counterexamples are adjectives. You can no more "uninsane" people than you could have "insaned" them in the first place.

Comment: Too bad you also cannot uninundate something

Comment: @Stan: And that's a shame.

Comment: *unindent* is another counter-example that comes to mind.

Comment: Related: [How productive is the verb prefix “un-”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/89701), [Is there a better word than unignore?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/340535), [Is “Unfavorite” a legit English verb?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/231617)

Answer (score 82, accepted):

1. *Insane* is the opposite of *sane*, from Latin *in-* “not” and *sanus*.
2. *Inaccessible* is the opposite of *accessible*, from Latin *in-* “not” and *accessibilis*.
3. *Inadequate* is the opposite of *adequate*, from *in-* and *adequate*.
4. *Install* is **not** the opposite of *stall*. It comes from Latin *installare*, from *in-* in the meaning “in” (not “not”) and *stallum*.

*Uninstall* is not a double negative. *Install* simply happens to begin with an *in*, much like *insert* (not the opposite of *sert*), *invert* (not the opposite of *vert*), *invent* (not the opposite of *vent*), *indicate* (not the opposite of *dicate*), *include* (not the opposite of *clude*), etc.

**Edit:** here are a few more words beginning with *unin-*:

- from *in-*: unintentional, unindexed, uninclined, uninfected, uninquiring, uninjected, uninitiate, uninformative, unincluded, unindent, unintuitive, uninvitingly
- from *inter-*: uninteresting, unintelligent, unintelligible, uninterpretable, uninterpolated...

Courtesy of [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Index%3aEnglish/u).

Comment: I think it points the _unin_ mistake done by the OP. But it seems to me that for something to be _uninstalled_ it does not need for it to have been installed once, like _unmounted_ does not presupose the thing to have ever been mounted. So I guess, given the meaning of _removing software which is installed_, deinstall would be much more meaningful. At least, uninstalled can mean that you have some software but you haven't installed yet, so it is not-installed or uninstalled which is not the way we use the word when talking about software.

Comment: @Trinidad: it's actually even more complicated than that: there are two different *un-* s in English. The one that applies to adjectives usually means "not" — *unusual*, *uncertain*, *unattractive*, *unhelpful*. The other *un-* applies to verbs and generally means "do the opposite thing" — *undo*, *undress*, *uncover*. Hence the confusion about the meaning of *uninstallED*, which could be a verb or an adjective. But there is no confusion whatsoever about the meaning of *to uninstall*, which is clearly a verb. You cannot *uninstall* something that's not there. There is no ambiguity.

Comment: I like the idea of "cluding a rationale" in my documents, meaning that I left it out.

Comment: @KazDragon Too bad we already have *exclude* for that purpose.

Answer (score 18):

What Reg says. I'd like to add that you are not the only one who is reluctant to use "uninstall" for one reason or another, as I have heard similar complaints elsewere. I think there are two other things that add to this dislike:

- "Un" followed by "in" sounds almost like a duplicate syllable, which generally doesn't sound good.
- If you were to negate a prefixed verb in Latin or needed a verb with opposite meaning, you would usually not simply add another prefix, but rather replace the old suffix, as in *increase–decrease*, *inhale–exhale*, *convert–revert*, etc. Using *unin-* clearly marks the word as a hybrid construction. Note that hybrid constructions go further than mere Anglicising: instead of only adjusting the sound of the foreign word a bit and inflecting it, as in Anglicisation, whole new dictionary articles are being created. Of course we use hybrid constructions all the time, and a great many now feel completely natural; but a newfangled odour might still cling to some newly formed ones, though it remains unclear why some are immediately acceptable while others are not (like *unrevertableness*). I think prefixes are generally harder to swallow than suffixes, like *-able*.

Probably owing in part to these considerations, alternatives have been proposed, like *deinstall* and simply *remove*, which I think are both acceptable, and even *exstall*, which nobody would understand. While I have some sympathy with those who resist new words, there comes a time when we need to give up; I think that time has come for *uninstall*. It is still not my favourite word of all times, but I won't stop using it now. At least it is not gaudy, like many new words from the advertising business.

Comment: Perform reverse installation!

Comment: Hmm, I like outstall myself!

Comment: exstall sounds good!

Answer (score 15):

It's un-install, not unin-stall!

Comment: Exactly. And over the years, it got shortened to uninstall.

Answer (score 5):

Shouldn't it more logically be *disinstall* by analogy with *disinvite, disinfect, disinherit, disinter*?  But it's too late... the software developers have already invented the word; we can't disinvent it.

Comment: Funny but in Russian it is "desinfect". Why is it?

Comment: Actually, not all your examples work. "Disinherit" is in no sense a converse of "inherit"; "disinfect" is as likely to be used for preventing infection as removing it; and I don't recall ever having met "disinvite". But you're right that "uninstall" is historically unlikely: until recently almost all verbs in "un-" were about wrapping, enclosing, fastening.

Comment: @Colin: disinherit, disinter, disinvite and disinfect all share the idea that something has been done and then undone. For disinherit, that thing is not inheriting, but being named an heir. And for disinfect, the original meaning (which can be verified by searching Google books) was cleansing objects that had been exposed to patients with a contagious disease. I have indeed met disinvite, and it's also in the online Merriam-Webster dictionary, while uninvite is not. I see through Google, though, that uninvite is also commonly used in the same sense (i.e. withdraw an invitation from).

Comment: I don't agree. You're right about the origins of "disinfect", but I'm talking about how the word is used today. I certainly disagree about "disinherit": first, there is no "inherit" which is being undone, and second nobody needs to be "named an heir" in order to be disinherited - they just need to *be* an heir. I'm happy to believe in "disinvite" - I've just never encountered it before.

Comment: @PeterShor Perhaps deinstall is another option?